# Workday - REST API authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, workday-api

I'm trying to use the Workday REST API to fetch & update some workers data.
I'm having some difficulties to authenticate to it and the documentation is very poor on information to exploit the API.

I've followed this [link](https://cdn.cdata.com/help/JWH/py/pg_oauthcustomappcreate.htm), which give guidelines to create OAuth app inside Workday which is a pretty common thing for API authentication.

As I already have an ISU working, I've created an "API Client for Integrations" giving me an Client ID & secret.

The issue is that I manage to get an access_token using these information. Usually this CURL request should work to get my token :

```
 curl --location '{OAUTH_URL}/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {base64(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

But this returns :

```
{
 "error": "Invalid request"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of to achieve this ?

Thank you !

EDIT :

I've found a way to generate an access_token using **API client for Integrations** :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://{BASE_URL}/ccx/oauth2/{TENANT}/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=xxx'
```

But I cannot find a way to interact with Workday such as [Person API](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/restapi/index.html#person/v4/people). I'm always getting an error when trying to get `/people`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```bash
CLIENT_ID='***** your Client ID *******'
CLIENT_SECRET='***** your client secret ********'
CLIENT_ID_SECRET=$(echo -n $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET | base64 -w 0)
OAUTH_URL='***** workday auth URL ******'

curl --location --request POST $OAUTH_URL'/token' \
--silent \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic '$CLIENT_ID_SECRET \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Demo

Ran in the git bash terminal

```bash
CLIENT_ID='bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH'
CLIENT_SECRET='pQaE-ceDi3nFz'
CLIENT_ID_SECRET=$(echo -n $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET | base64 -w 0)
OAUTH_URL='http://localhost:3000'

curl --location --request POST $OAUTH_URL'/token' \
--silent \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic '$CLIENT_ID_SECRET \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

[image]

##### Generate cURL by Postman

Or can create cURL API by [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

It convert `base64` from client id, client secret

At `Authorization` tab, to select `Basic Auth`

The enter username / password by `client id` and `client secret`

[image]

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YkhScFkzVnNkSHd1WTI5dGNIOnBRYUUtY2VEaTNuRno='
```

Comment: Hi, that's what I'm already trying to do.

My CURL request inside my first post is identical and returns me the issue (having --request POST isn't mandatory here)

Comment: From this documentation in [here](https://cdn.cdata.com/help/JWH/py/pg_oauth.htm), OAuth is only supported when connecting with UseWQL. It means can't handling by cURL. It only by  API Client. Which provides by CData. Detail information in [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/workday-wql-raas.rst) at Connecting to the Workday WQL Service in [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/workday-wql-raas-8.png)

Comment: Mmh I get it.

Then how can we authenticate to the Workday REST Api to list and/or update Workers then ?

Comment: In the chrome, if press F12, Dev Tool shows. In the `Network` tab, you can see REST API (Post, Get and URL, header, payload) more detail in [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network)

Comment: I really don't see the the relevance with Chrome dev tools here. 

By the way I've found how to get an access_token with OAuth using API (updated post). 

But I cannot find a way to get workers profiles. If I can't I'll use SOAP requet instead of  REST

Comment: When you connecting to Workday WQL Service by browser (Chrome), F12 key will shows Dev Tool. Go to Netwark tab,  press sign-in then you can see REST API. Can you update how to get access_token in your question. SOAP call do you know WSDL URL?

Comment: Alright I get it, but I don't have access to Workday directly nor WQL service or Community, so I can't test that unfortunatly. Post as already been updated. 
For SOAP I'll have to dig to get the WSDL URL, I don't have it right now

Comment: Happy to here you  can get access - toke by cURL, can you accept my answer and let me know if you got WSDL URL, SoapUI can help to access your soap service.